# MYSQL Workbench csv file not importing all the data from csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, mysql-workbench

I am using MySql Workbench Data Import facility to import a .csv file but it only imports 149 records.

I get message `149 records imported`

My csv file looks as below:

```
request_id,name,dc,create_date,ostype,appinId,applnname,applnshtname,applicationstatus,environmentname,environment_type,virtual_host,ip_address,ip_endpoint_domain,errorsreasons,computer_system_host_name,computer_system_assetlifecyclestatus,vm_host,computer_system_operatingsystemtypename,computer_system_operatingsystemname,computer_system_operatingsystemversion,buildstatus,isg_turnover_status,gis_turnover_status,application_development_support,application_production_support,application_qa_support,application_technical_contact,information_custodian,information_steward,infrastructure_support,technical_contact
294694,abc12cdisiapd024,OCE,6/27/2017 22:37,Linux,2002,CDI Services Interface,CDISI,Production,CDISI.OCE-DEV,Development,sv730esx0080,10.211.127.149,abc.COM,,abc12CDISIAPD024,Deployed,SV730ESX0080,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,WCDIMI,CDIMIFISI,WCDIMI,prasikda,aashok,speter,DSOSA,
294719,abc12dcsbapi005,OCE,6/28/2017 2:25,Linux,6243,DMPD VTS DCS Batch,dcs-batch,Production,dcs-batch.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40003,10.207.71.1,abc.COM,,abc12DCSBAPI005,Deployed,SV730ESX40003,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MagellenAppS,MagellenAppS,MAGELLAN,,sobdas,,DSOSA,sevasude
294720,abc12dcsbapi006,OCE,6/28/2017 2:27,Linux,6243,DMPD VTS DCS Batch,dcs-batch,Production,dcs-batch.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40003,10.207.71.2,abc.COM,,abc12DCSBAPI006,Deployed,SV730ESX40003,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MagellenAppS,MagellenAppS,MAGELLAN,,sobdas,,DSOSA,sevasude
294721,abc12dcsbapi007,OCE,6/28/2017 2:29,Linux,6243,DMPD VTS DCS Batch,dcs-batch,Production,dcs-batch.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40003,10.207.71.3,abc.COM,,abc12DCSBAPI007,Deployed,SV730ESX40003,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MagellenAppS,MagellenAppS,MAGELLAN,,sobdas,,DSOSA,sevasude
294722,abc12dcsbapi008,OCE,6/28/2017 2:31,Linux,6243,DMPD VTS DCS Batch,dcs-batch,Production,dcs-batch.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40008,10.207.71.4,abc.COM,,abc12DCSBAPI008,Deployed,SV730ESX40002,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MagellenAppS,MagellenAppS,MAGELLAN,,sobdas,,DSOSA,sevasude
294724,abc12pasapi010,OCE,6/28/2017 2:35,Linux,6272,DMPD PAS Purchase Alerts Service,pas-services,Production,pas-services.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40008,10.207.71.6,abc.COM,,abc12PASAPI010,Deployed,SV730ESX40002,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MAGELLAN,MagellenAppS,MagellanQA,,sobdas,,DSOSA,rkannapp
294725,abc12pasapi012,OCE,6/28/2017 2:39,Linux,6272,DMPD PAS Purchase Alerts Service,pas-services,Production,pas-services.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40002,10.207.71.8,abc.COM,,abc12PASAPI012,Deployed,SV730ESX40002,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MAGELLAN,MagellenAppS,MagellanQA,,sobdas,,DSOSA,rkannapp
294727,abc12pasapi013,OCE,6/28/2017 2:43,Linux,6273,DMPD PAS Purchase Alerts Web,vca-web,Production,vca-web.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40002,10.207.71.9,abc.COM,,abc12PASAPI013,Deployed,SV730ESX40002,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MAGELLAN,MagellenAppS,MagellanQA,,sobdas,,DSOSA,bipjha
294728,abc12pasapi015,OCE,6/28/2017 2:47,Linux,6273,DMPD PAS Purchase Alerts Web,vca-web,Production,vca-web.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40002,10.207.71.11,abc.COM,,abc12PASAPI015,Deployed,SV730ESX40002,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MAGELLAN,MagellenAppS,MagellanQA,,sobdas,,DSOSA,bipjha
294729,abc12pasapi016,OCE,6/28/2017 2:49,Linux,6273,DMPD PAS Purchase Alerts Web,vca-web,Production,vca-web.AACERT3,Integration,sv730esx40002,10.207.71.12,abc.COM,,abc12PASAPI016,Deployed,SV730ESX40002,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,MAGELLAN,MagellenAppS,MagellanQA,,sobdas,,DSOSA,bipjha
294790,abc12cdisiapd025,OCE,6/27/2017 22:40,Linux,2002,CDI Services Interface,CDISI,Production,CDISI.OCE-DEV,Development,sv730esx0080,10.211.127.150,abc.COM,,abc12CDISIAPD025,Deployed,SV730ESX0080,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,WCDIMI,CDIMIFISI,WCDIMI,prasikda,aashok,speter,DSOSA
```

My line separator is `CRLF` and I have choosen `CRLF` in configuration import settings. I am using `,` as field separator and Encoding as utf-8

Lines `147 - 153`

```
302577,abc12erpdbq009,CDE,7/3/2017 21:15,Linux,2746,SSO for GIFS,SSO for GIFS,Production,SSO for GIFS.CDE-QA,QA,sv730esx1052,10.211.182.63,abc.COM,,abc12ERPDBQ009,Deployed,SV730ESX1052,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,GIFSFUNC,,GIFSFUNC,hchang,chazra,chazra,DSSAO,
302578,abc12erpdbq012,CDE,7/3/2017 21:22,Linux,2746,SSO for GIFS,SSO for GIFS,Production,SSO for GIFS.CDE-QA,QA,sv730esx1052,10.211.182.66,abc.COM,,abc12ERPDBQ012,Deployed,SV730ESX1050,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,GIFSFUNC,,GIFSFUNC,hchang,chazra,chazra,DSSAO,
302579,abc12erpdbd026,CDE,7/3/2017 21:24,Linux,2746,SSO for GIFS,SSO for GIFS,Production,SSO for GIFS.CDE-DEV,Development,sv730esx1052,10.211.182.67,abc.COM,,abc12ERPDBD026,Deployed,SV730ESX1052,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,GIFSFUNC,,GIFSFUNC,hchang,chazra,chazra,DSSAO,
302582,abc12erpdbd030,CDE,7/3/2017 21:29,Linux,2746,SSO for GIFS,SSO for GIFS,Production,SSO for GIFS.CDE-DEV,Development,sv730esx1052,10.211.182.71,abc.COM,,abc12ERPDBD030,Deployed,SV730ESX1052,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,GIFSFUNC,,GIFSFUNC,hchang,chazra,chazra,DSSAO,
302586,SW730VIAMPA003,CDE,7/4/2017 0:05,Windows,6617,Identity and Access Management – abc.COM,abcIAM,Planned,abcIAM.Prod,Production,sv730esx5045,10.46.33.56,EDGE.abc.COM,,SW730VIAMPA003,Deployed,SV730ESX5039,Windows,Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard,6.3.9600,Being Built,Turnover Pending,Turnover Complete,WEXTPLAT,,WVOLQA,sadacher,nmathew,dluther,WEXTPLAT,
302587,SW730VIAMPA004,CDE,7/4/2017 0:07,Windows,6617,Identity and Access Management – abc.COM,abcIAM,Planned,abcIAM.Prod,Production,sv730esx5045,10.46.33.57,EDGE.abc.COM,,SW730VIAMPA004,Deployed,SV730ESX5045,Windows,Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard,6.3.9600,Being Built,Turnover Pending,Turnover Complete,WEXTPLAT,,WVOLQA,sadacher,nmathew,dluther,WEXTPLAT,
302623,abc12rpsocapd013,CDE,7/4/2017 3:45,Linux,6345,RPS Global Operating Certificates,RPS OpCerts,Planned,RPS OpCerts.RPSOC_Development,Development,sv730esx1052,10.211.127.187,abc.COM,,abc12RPSOCAPD013,Deployed,SV730ESX1052,Linux,Linux,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo),Being Built,,Turnover Complete,WINTBILL,,WBILLREP,sranga,rchakkun,mgandepa,WOPCERT
```

Please let me know what can i do to import each and every record.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us records 148 through 152.  I am guessing there is a problem with your CSV file, and maybe we can see what it is.

Comment: edited my question. the import completes after `149` records

Comment: do you think hyphen in `Identity and Access Management – abc.COM` is causing issue? I don't see records starting from `302586` in the table

Comment: No...line 147 also uses hyphens yet it got imported.  Maybe you have some strange EOL characters in there.

Comment: I have checked in notepad++ EOL is `CRLF`  So that doesn't look issue here. Line `147` has hyphens but no space before and after the hyphen but `302586` has spaces before and after hyphen

Comment: Well then test your conjecture.  Remove those hyphens and then see if the import completes, or at least gets further than 149.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161259/discussion-between-meallhour-and-tim-biegeleisen).